# Editing information

Tags: ios4

I am doing a calendar event. Once run the application, it will show a calendar with a table  view below of the days events. Once clicked the events, it will go to another view to show the details. All this are with arrays read  from memory and passed on. When i want to edit the event name, it goes to a view with a table with all the event names used and with a cell clicked, i want to go back to my previous view and change the name to the one i selected but the problem is when i read the thing from the memory. So i must change in the memory. i tried
`[[mainDelegate.personArray objectAtIndex:i]setEventname:newname]`, but when i restart application, it is no longer there.

Comment: Some code please. Also, are you using the EventKit framework? If not, if you are not using a static store to store your events (e.g. saved to file or database), as soon as you quit the program, all items in the memory is going to be GONE.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution (from where you are now) would be to store the array in the user defaults. After modifying the `mainDelegate.personArray` call `[mainDelegate commitSettings]` and add something like this to `mainDelegate`:

```
-(void)commitSettings
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.personArray
                                              forKey:@"personArr"];

    // you may leave this one out for non-critical data:
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

and when starting the app, read in the array like this:

```
self.personArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"personArr"];
```